# get JSON with functions from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use [JQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate forms on my webapp. I can pass JQuery Validate a list of rules to use to validate my form like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    age: {
      required: true,
      min: 3
    },
    parent: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $("#age").val() < 13;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now I would like to generate those validation rules on the server instead of coding them in my JavaScript, do an $.ajax request to get them, attach them to the form and be all set.

But this

```
   {
      rules: {
        age: {
          required: true,
          min: 3
        },
        parent: {
          required: function(element) {
            return $("#age").val() < 13;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

is not valid JSON, because there is the function declaration. Is there a way to do this?

To elaborate: my application is made of static HTML and JS, and my only interaction with the server is with some REST services that return JSON.
So when I get a person from the server because I want to edit it in a form, I do

```
$.ajax({url: '/person/1',
   success: function(data) {
      /* fill form fields */
      ...
      /* get validation rules from server and attach to form
         something like */
      $.ajax({url: '/person/validation_rules',
         success: function(rules) {
            /* something like */
            $('#myform').validate(rules);
         }
   }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: A JavaScript function is not a valid datatype for JSON, convert it into a String then use `eval` (since you trust the source) and execute it that way.

Comment: @Anders - that's overkill...you're going to go from a JS literal on the server, to a JSON string, with a String-encoded function, then send it over the wire, deserialize the JSON string, and then decode the function? Why not just send it as a literal in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply returning it as a JS literal, instead of as JSON?

**Edit:**

Your original description included:

```
    {
      rules: {
        age: {
          required: true,
          min: 3
        },
        parent: {
          required: function(element) {
            return $("#age").val() < 13;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

That's a JS literal, not a JSON *string*, and is completely valid to return from the server, in and of itself. No additional changes necessary, and the function declaration is just fine. JSON is simply a subset of the JS literal. (http://www.json.org/js.html).

So, you could easily return that structure from your server, via some AJAX request, exactly as it is.

For more details: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/json_is_a_subse

Comment: What do you mean with JS literal? A JS <script>...</script>? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already generating Javascript on the server, you don't need to load it as JSON. If you are loading this function from `http://myserver.com/validation.js`, instead of calling it with ajax, just call it from the script tag, eg.

```
<script src="http://myserver.com/validation.js"></script>
```

You will also need to edit slightly generated code:

```
 var validationRule = {
      rules: {
        age: {
          required: true,
          min: 3
        },
        parent: {
          required: function(element) {
            return $("#age").val() < 13;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

then your validation will look like

```
$("#myform").validate(validationRule);
```

**EDIT:** if server response must be JSON, you can get it as a string and eval() it. or you can arrange some valid json which you can tweak to desired form, say:

```
{
    ...
    "minParentAge": 13
}
```

and then construct function from it.

Comment: Thanks Slartibartfast. Wouldn't that generate a global variable for every rule? I'm a bit concerned about namespace pollution.

Comment: How many rules are there? You could make one `rules` object and have specivic rules as its fields, I guess.

Comment: One for every entity/every form I have on my app. A lot. But if this is the only way I can live with it and make a global array with validation rules. It's not that nice, but would work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single global variable as your root namespace - just like third party libraries like jQuery do. Call it for instance `MyNamespace`.

Then load js files that populate this namespace, that way you get a minimal DOM footprint.

My preferred way is doing it like this:

```
<myFunctions.js>

MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

(function(){

  function utilityFunction1() {
    //....
  }

  function utilityFunction2() {
    //....
  }

  MyNamespace.UtilityFunctions = {
    utilityFunction1: utilityFunction1,
    utilityFunction2: utilityFunction2
  };

})();


</myFunctions.js>
```

then include it like always

```
<script src="myFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```